# creating multiple rows from multiple list using same Id, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe like this, Column: `ID` and `Main`

```
ID,Main
0,[30 115 266 38;662 99 1199 43] [511 133 25 47] [664 162 49 22]
```

How do I make my dataframe something like below using pandas

Expected Output

```
ID,Main
0,30 115 266 38
0,662 99 1199 43
0,511 133 25 47
0,664 162 49 22
```

Comment: What is `print (type(df['Main'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: it is `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `;` by `][` and then extract values between `[]` by [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for `Series` of `list`s.

Last create `DataFrame`, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with some data cleaning by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
s = df['Main'].fillna('').str.replace(';','][').str.findall('\[(.*?)\]')
df = (pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
df.columns = ['ID','Main']
print (df)
   ID            Main
0   0   30 115 266 38
1   0  662 99 1199 43
2   0   511 133 25 47
3   0   664 162 49 22
```

Another solution for `Series`:

```
s = df['Main'].fillna('').str.strip('[]').str.split(';|\]\s+\[')
```

Comment: thanks but it is giving me an error `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` while creating dataframe

Comment: @J.David - It means some `NaN` values in `s`, give me some time.

Comment: @J.David - Added solution for working with NaNs with sample data.

Comment: Doesn't `df.Main = df.Main.fillna('')` do the job? If i'm not mistaken, the output won't contain the lines with `NaN` values.

Comment: @ysearka -Yes, you are right -  `s = df['Main'].fillna('').str.replace(';','][').str.findall('\[(.*?)\]')`

Comment: @ysearka - Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael no problem, glad I could help and thanks for another elegant solution in pandas!

Comment: @jezrael For sample like this: `199,[563 109 266 33;791 96 1070 76;1 122 70 37] [] [497 171 22 25]`, it is not working properly. I dont know why.

Comment: @J.David - Do you use first or second solution?

Comment: i used the first one

Comment: @J.David - Check email.